# Trouble scrolling 2 ScrollViews on a FrameLayout

Tags: android, scrollview, android-framelayout

I have a **FrameLayout** which has a **ScrollView** as the only child. During runtime I inflate a **RelativeLayout** which has a **ScrollView** within and add it to the **FrameLayout** (This child view now overlaps the previous ScrollView). I have used a [LockableScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763304/disable-scrollview-programmatically) as the first child of the FrameLayout so, I can disable it's scrolling by setting the **scrollable** property to false, the focusable and clickable properties are also set to false after the new child is added to the FrameLayout. But still I'm unable to scroll the new ScrollView. Any pointers?

The following is the Root layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/questions_bg">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/questions_header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/header_bg" />

        <com.package.ui.LockableScrollView
            android:id="@+id/question_scrollview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/questions_header"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
            android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
            android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <!-- Some more views -->

        </com.package.ui.LockableScrollView>    
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

The following is the child layout that is inflated during runtime and added to the FrameLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/q_map_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/en_question_map_header" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/q_map_bg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/q_map_header"
        android:src="@drawable/question_map_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/q_map_footer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/q_map_bg"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/en_question_map_footer" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/q_map_header"
        android:layout_above="@id/q_map_footer"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/q_map_header"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/q_map_header"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/q_map_grid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:numColumns="5"
            android:verticalSpacing="8dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hu Raghnath, Can you post your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't place a scrollable container (Here GridView) within another scrollable container (Here ScrollView).