# Scroll View is not working properly Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I Want to create a design like [this](http://s17.postimg.org/rhx8qfpdb/Capture.png) image .

I want independent scroll on both left and right side

What i have done that i have created a main layout .In that i am inflating the inner design at run time .So the deign is proper now.But i have done some silly mistake .Because of that the the scroll is coming inside the layout .So please see the code and help me i am new in android

**Class**

```
void setData(){
        flightResult=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.flightResultData);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams flightDetailsLayout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

         LinearLayout.LayoutParams forUnderLine = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         forUnderLine.setMargins(0,0, 0, 0);

         flightDetailsLayout.setMargins(0, 40, 0, 0);
            for(int i=0;i < 13;i++){
                TextView line=new TextView(this);
                 line.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.shape_line);
                 line.setLayoutParams(forUnderLine);
                 if(i!=0){
                     flightResult.addView(line);  
                 }
                  LinearLayout flightInformations=(LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.flight_details_layout, null);
                  flightLogo=(ImageView)flightInformations.findViewById(R.id.onewayflightLogo);
                  flightCompany = (TextView)flightInformations.findViewById(R.id.onewayflightName);
                  flightLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.airindia);
                  flightCompany.setText("AirIndia");

              flightResult.addView(flightInformations);
            }
            TextView dummy=new TextView(this);
            dummy.setLayoutParams(flightDetailsLayout);
            flightResult.addView(dummy);
    }
```

**Main Layout** (where i am infalting to flightResultData)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/top_bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/back_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/back_btn"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
            android:text="@string/flightHeader"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/flightDetailsLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainLinearLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/gray_bg123"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/innerflightDetailsLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/from"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="Boston to San Fransisco, "
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tripType"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:text="RoundTrip"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/innerTripLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tripDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:text="19 Jan 2013 " 
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/paxText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="for 1 Adults,0 Childs,O Infants"
                android:textSize="12dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Book"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tripDate"
                android:layout_width="84dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                android:text="Rs 10,2345 "
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bookBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:src="@drawable/book" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sortFlightLayouts"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/flightDetailsLayout"
        android:background="@drawable/gray_bg123"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="DEL-BLR"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/flight_icon_result" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/time" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/rupee" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/gray_bg123"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="BLR-DEL"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/flight_icon_result" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/time" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/rupee" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/flightResultData"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sortFlightLayouts"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footerLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/top_bg" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/filter" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sort" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**details_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainResultLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/returnScrollView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/oneWayResultData"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/onewayflightLogo"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/spicejet" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/onewayflightName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="SpiceJet" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/onewayflightNumber"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="9W - 496" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/onewayflightTime"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                        android:minLines="1"
                        android:text="06:00 - 7:05"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/onewayflightDuration"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:minLines="1"
                        android:text="1h 35m | Non Stop"
                        android:textSize="10dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/onewayflightAmount"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:minLines="1"
                        android:text="Rs 20,0000"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/returnScrollView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/returnResultData"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/returnflightLogo"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/spicejet" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/returnflightName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                        android:text="Spice jet" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/returnflightNumber"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                        android:text="8W - 356" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/returnflightTime"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                        android:minLines="1"
                        android:text="06:00 - 7:05"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/returnflightDuration"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:minLines="1"
                        android:text="1h 35m | Non Stop"
                        android:textSize="10sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/returnflightAmount"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:minLines="1"
                        android:text="Rs 20,0000"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not surprised you're having difficulties with xml layouts as complicated as that.  Why don't you break it into smaller easier to manage ones which you can inflate into the spaces. I.e top level has placeholders for header, then the two scrollviews, and placeholder for the footer. Then create a header and footer layout and a layout for the contents of each scrollview row. I would also very strongly recommend not hard coding layouts if you want any chance of them looking correct on more than just your development device

Comment: i accept your suggestion i am new in android development but i will do this sure thanks for a good suggestion

Comment: but as of now i need some solutions of the question

Comment: Take a look at my answer :)

Comment: rather i would suggest you to use two listviews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a look at the layout XML and have found your problem. In one layout you are trying to define both scrollviews and their contents.  You don't want to be doing this.  I would also suggest you don't want a scrollview, but a listview.

Take a look at [This](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) tutorial on how to create listviews with custom contents and create an arrayadapter to populate it with data.

This is an example of how your main layout could look:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llHeader"
            android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lvDepartures"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lvArrivals"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llFooter"
            android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This gives you three vertical sections weighted DYNAMICALLY so it looks the same on any device screen in proportions 1:4:1. Then the middle section is split down the middle with two listviews which are independently scrollable which you can populate using an adapter.

Then you want to create a SINGLE layout for "a flight"

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="75sp"
            android:layout_height="75sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
            android:id="@+id/ivDemoIcon"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Demo Name"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
            android:id="@+id/tvDemoName"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivDemoIcon"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivChevron"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivDemoIcon"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivChevron"
            android:text="Date Version"
            android:id="@+id/tvDateVersion"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvDemoName"/>

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ivChevron"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivDemoIcon"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ivDemoIcon"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This layout has space for two icons as well as three sections of text nicely layed out.  You can move these about and create the layout as you want with the information you want.  Always try and make layouts as generic as possible so you can use it over and over.

You can then use your adapter to populate each element of each listview for each flight with an instance of this "flight" layout (I've been too lazy to tweak it to be a flight layout like yours but you should get the gist).

You can then create a header and footer layout which the textviews and imageviews etc can be set at runtime accoring to what flight information you have.  For the flight information, I would strongly suggest using a singleton data class accessible from anywhere and store the information in ArrayLists (Listview adapters etc play VERY nicely with arraylists and you can do all sorts of cool things like sorting and filtering)

The beauty of clever coding is making everything as dynamic and reusable as you can. Don't go hardcoding things or creating lots of layouts for the same thing, Reuse and recycle! Will make your job much easier. Hope this has helped

Comment: i am trying this but i want to tell you one thing that ..on both side the data will be different so how could i use different loop to fill the values in that dynamically

Comment: In the java code you set an adapter for each listview with each adapter being fed data from an array list or other such data structure. Your adapter can then decide what it chooses to populate the listview view with

Comment: i have created the layout now will u please help me how could i populate the data.should i post me new XML code please help me i am to new i am not able to understand how i will do that please help me

Comment: Have you managed to get this working?  Take a look at the tutorial I linked.Maybe direct message me if you're still having issues and I can attempt to help.  You may be best off starting with a simple tutorial with a single listview and then building up to more complex layouts so you don't overwhelm yourself