# How to apply gesture inside scrollview in Android

Tags: android, scrollview, gesture, epub

I am developing Android application which contains the reading of epub books. In that I need to place two pages in book view. If those pages exceed the screen size user have to scroll and view the books and have to pinch zoom the book and user can pan the book for reading.

At first I tried to place two webview inside the Relativelayout. I can achieve this by placing relativelayout inside the scrollview and horizontal scrollview to scroll in both horizontal and vertical.

But problem occur in the swipping of pages and pinchzoom is not working inside the scrollview; it remains in the first page itself. I don't know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting WebView inside ScrollView? It functions funny that way. You'll have to disable the outside ScrollView if you're doing so.

You can modify `ScrollView` to be lockable, as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5763815/1402526).