# Scrollview inside of a scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

**BEFORE YOU SAY** *"Google says not to do this"* **PLEASE READ ALL OF MY QUESTION!!**

The layout:

`ScrollView -> RelativeLayout -> ScrollView -> RelativeLayout`

The *first* ScrollView is necessary because form entries pull up the soft keyboard on some phones which hides the rest of the content. Having a ScrollView as the outer most container allows a user to scroll with the soft keyboard present.

The *second* ScrollView lower on the hierarchy is a ListView which is still scrollable.

I completely understand why devs are discouraged to have a ScrollView within another ScrollView. I need to figure out a way to get the two to work together. I *tried* disabling the outermost ScrollView when the inner most ScrollView get's a touch, but that didn't help.

Is there a way to get around this to where both will work (not at the same time of course)? I wouldn't even mind disabling the outermost ScrollView until the content page is changed again. There has to be a way..

Comment: "The second ScrollView lower on the hierarchy is a ListView which is still scrollable." -- `ScrollView` != `ListView`. "I need to figure out a way to get the two to work together" -- or, you could replace the `ListView` with a `Spinner`.

Comment: @CommonsWare the `Spinner` idea would work great, but unfortunately the list is of 20 or so articles with title, date, and teaser so I need a way to show it all with a custom layout :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to programmatically ***intercept*** the touch events form the outer most scrollview. I am using a class that I found in another SOF about [Disabling a ScrollView Programattically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763304/disable-scrollview-programmatically).

Answer (score 4):

Step #1: Remove the `ScrollView`.

Step #2: Make the first `RelativeLayout` be a header in your `ListView` via `addHeaderView()`.

Step #3: Make the second `RelativeLayout` be a footer in your `ListView` via `addFooterView()`.

The net effect is that the whole thing will be scrollable, without nested scrollable items.

Comment: +1 Snazzy solution. I'll see if I can make that work with the design.

Answer (score 0):

It will only work when you set the android:layout_height to a fixed value for your second  ScrollView. The best way is to set a size depending on device, for that it would be better to create layout for each supported screen size ( value on dp like 150 dp).
you shoud create separate layout: layout-small, layout-normal, layout-large ....
see this link for optimization of the fixed size: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html