# How to disable and enable the scrolling on android ScrollView?

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I am a android developer.I also want to use a ScrollView.This ScrollView need to some time disable scrolling  and Some time enable scrolling .But i can no able to disable the scrolling .How to i implement it .Please help to me.I also try to use the some code such a s

```
fullparentscrolling.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
fullparentscrolling.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
```

or

```
 fullparentscrolling.setEnabled(false);
```

But it does not work.

Comment: You need to create custom scrollview by extending scrollview

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Try this way

Create Your CustomScrollview like this

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class CustomScrollView extends ScrollView {

    private boolean enableScrolling = true;

    public boolean isEnableScrolling() {
        return enableScrolling;
    }

    public void setEnableScrolling(boolean enableScrolling) {
        this.enableScrolling = enableScrolling;
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        if (isEnableScrolling()) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
       if (isEnableScrolling()) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
       } else {
           return false;
       }
}
}
```

In your xml

// "com.example.demo" replace with your packagename

```
<com.example.demo.CustomScrollView
        android:id="@+id/myScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </com.example.demo.CustomScrollView>
```

In your Activity

```
CustomScrollView myScrollView = (CustomScrollView) findViewById(R.id.myScroll);
        myScrollView.setEnableScrolling(false); // disable scrolling
        myScrollView.setEnableScrolling(true); // enable scrolling
```

Comment: This worked for my nested scrollview situation as well, where in I needed to disable the nested scrollView until the parent scrollView was completely scrolled to the top.  My solution can be viewed here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33685636/518116

Answer (score 30):

I set the on touch listener for the scroll view and in the onTouch method i returend true.
That did the trick for me.

```
mScrollView.setOnTouchListener( new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
            {
                  return true;
            }
});
```

Best for all

Comment: and don't forget to 'extends ScrollView'

Comment: Also, if you want scrollview to not consume touch events - `return false`

Answer (score 11):

You cannot disable the scrolling of a ScrollView. You would need to extend to ScrollView and override the onTouchEvent method to return false when some condition is matched.

You could modify ScrollView as follows to disable scrolling

```
class LockableScrollView extends ScrollView {

    ...

    // true if we can scroll (not locked)
    // false if we cannot scroll (locked)
    private boolean mScrollable = true;

    public void setScrollingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        mScrollable = enabled;
    }

    public boolean isScrollable() {
        return mScrollable;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // if we can scroll pass the event to the superclass
                if (mScrollable) return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
                // only continue to handle the touch event if scrolling enabled
                return mScrollable; // mScrollable is always false at this point
            default:
                return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // Don't do anything with intercepted touch events if 
        // we are not scrollable
        if (!mScrollable) return false;
        else return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }

}
```

for furthe reference here is the complete solution on stack overflow too!
[Disable ScrollView Programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763304/disable-scrollview-programmatically)

mark this as answer for others help..thank you

Answer (score -11):

Try this, this will disable the scroll function.

```
scrollview.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: I also already try to it but id does not working