# Android SetNestedScrollingEnabled not called?

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I have a nested child scrollview that is set to disable scrolling until the parent scrollview completes scrolling up.  Setting the `childScrollView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` works initially, and is reenabled `childScrollView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true)` after the parent is scrolled up completely.  However, while this is working, I want to again disable the nested scrollview after the parent is scrolled to the bottom, but it's not working.  Any ideas?

**MainActivity (snippet) :**

```
ResponsiveScrollView parentScroll = (ResponsiveScrollView) findViewById(R.id.parentScroll);

final ScrollView childScroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.childScroll);

childScroll.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); // disabled by default

parentScroll.setOnEndScrollListener(new PriorityNestedScrollView.OnEndScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onUpEndScroll() {
        Log.i(TAG, "scrolling up has ended"); // successfully fires

        childScroll.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true); // working...
    }

    @Override
    public void onDownEndScroll() {
        Log.i(TAG, "scrolling down has ended"); // successfully fires

        childScroll.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); // not working...
    }
});
```

**ResponsiveScrollView (snippet) :**

```
@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int x, int y, int oldX, int oldY) {
    super.onScrollChanged(x, y, oldX, oldY);

    // scroll up ended
    if (y >= END) {
        if (onEndScrollListener != null) {
            onEndScrollListener.onUpEndScroll();
        }
    }

    // scroll down ended
    if (y <= START) {
        if (onEndScrollListener != null) {
            onEndScrollListener.onDownEndScroll();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I accomplished this.  I intercept the nested scroll touch events until the parent has reached the top.

**ResponsiveScrollView :**

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (isEnableScrolling()) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

...

boolean enableScrolling = false // disabled by default

public boolean isEnableScrolling() {
    return enableScrolling;
}

public void setEnableScrolling(boolean enableScrolling) {
    this.enableScrolling = enableScrolling;
}
```

**MainActivity :**

```
@Override
public void onUpEndScroll() {
    Log.i(TAG, "scrolling up has ended");

    parentScroll.setEnableScrolling(true); // enable scrolling
}

@Override
public void onDownEndScroll() {
    Log.i(TAG, "scrolling down has ended");

    parentScroll.setEnableScrolling(false); // disable scrolling
}
```