# Android disbled scrollView on MapFragment long click

Tags: android, android-scrollview, onlongclicklistener, mapfragment

I have an `Activity` in which I have several `EditText`s and `MapFragment` , etc. The XML of this activity is a `ScrollView`. How could I do so that when the user make a long click on the map ( to fix its position) the scroll stop working, and once again done this work? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have first to check for the click on the map, so set an onClickListener on the Map. Trigger a countdown of 10 sec in this listener.
Then i recommand you to implement your Custom ScrollView like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18893487/5828664) shows.