# Custom scrollview crashes with error inflating class while referring to xml file line

Tags: java, android, xml, android-scrollview

since my `ScrollView` seems to override click events on the dynamically created views inside the layout `dynamic_content` inside it, I have been trying to implement a custom `ScrollView`. However, my app keeps crashing and giving the error "*Error inflating class*", and "*Didn't find class "..." on path*".

Here is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.example.test4.MainActivity.CustomScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/dynamic_content_scroll"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/dynamic_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</com.example.test4.MainActivity.CustomScrollView>
```

I have been trying to implement a Custom scrollView with java code created by Biraj Zalavadia in this question: [How to disable and enable the scrolling on android ScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893198/how-to-disable-and-enable-the-scrolling-on-android-scrollview/18893487):

```
public class CustomScrollView extends ScrollView {

    private boolean enableScrolling = true;

    public boolean isEnableScrolling() {
        return enableScrolling;
    }

    public void setEnableScrolling(boolean enableScrolling) {
        this.enableScrolling = enableScrolling;
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        if (isEnableScrolling()) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (isEnableScrolling()) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Attempts:**

I have tried a myriad of naming variations in the view name `com.example.test4.MainActivity.CustomScrollView` (this is the name received from Android Studio's autofill function), but I keep receiving the error "*java.lang.ClassNotFoundException*". Other variants include `CustomScrollView`, `com.example.test4.CustomScrollView`, `MainActivity.CustomScrollView`, and `test4.CustomScrollView`. On the other hand, the default ScrollView works.

Here is the logcat:

```
2019-01-03 22:18:19.496 26790-26790/com.example.test4 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.test4, PID: 26790
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test4/com.example.test4.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #67: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class com.example.test4.MainActivity.CustomScrollView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2792)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2870)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1601)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6590)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #67: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class com.example.test4.MainActivity.CustomScrollView
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class com.example.test4.MainActivity.CustomScrollView
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.test4.MainActivity.CustomScrollView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.test4-yb5Lg51_OfTw3mpgSsJETw==/base.apk",
 ... (trimmed) ..., nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.test4-yb5Lg51_OfTw3mpgSsJETw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:965)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:859)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.example.test4.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:327)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7023)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7014)
```

**Problem:**

Basically, I want to fix the xml-derived error ClassNotFoundException received when trying to use a custom scrollview.

Comment: Is your custom scrollview an inner class of MainActivity? Does it work if you move it to a separate .java file (and update your view tags)?

Comment: @BenP. Hello, I think so, it is inside `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {}`. Do you mean creating a new java file and then importing it to MainActivity?

Comment: You've pasted `CustomScrollView` source code. What is the name of the file that code is in? Is it in `MainActivity.java`? I recommend putting it in its own file named `CustomScrollView.java`.

Comment: @BenP. Thank you, it works now! You can make an answer so I can assign it. Now the view namespace is `com.example.test4.CustomScrollView`. I guess not only renaming it was enough, but it had to be in a separate file.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it is a good idea to put custom view subclasses in their own `.java` files. It looks like your `CustomScrollView` class might be an inner class of `MainActivity.java`; try moving it to `CustomScrollView.java` as a standalone class.

Note that if you do this, you'll have to update your layout `<CustomScrollView>` tags, since they currently reference `MainActivity.CustomScrollView`.