# How to disable vertical scroll in CalendarView?

Tags: android, api, scroll, resolution, calendarview

I'm new to Android. I'm using a `calendarView` in an `Activity` and it's showing properly (horizontal scroll) in most devices but it's scrolling vertically in some others. I don't know if it's due to API version or (low) screen resolution.

`CalendarView` scrolling vertically:

[image]

I need to know how to force horizontal scroll or how to prevent `CalendarView` from scrolling in those devices.

Comment: Check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893198/how-to-disable-and-enable-the-scrolling-on-android-scrollview