# RecyclerView for messenger application

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, messenger

I have converted the chat layout from listView to RecyclerView.

Now m facing some problem, When new messages arrive then it not showing automatically, I have to manually scroll to that messages.

Earlier in ListView it working.

I have used set setStackFormEnd in recylerView.

I want feature like whatsapp has like

if new message arrives and you are able to view last message then it will show that messages but

if you scrolling the messages then it doesn't change the position.

```
    layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    messagesView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    messagesView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    messagesView.addOnScrollListener(mOnScrollListener);
```

Sample on Create Code Code

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)    findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
final Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_is_reverse);
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerDecoration(this));
adapter = new SampleAdapter(items);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    items.add("Items" +items.size());
    adapter.notifyItemInserted(items.size());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true)
yourRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Comment: @Arbitur check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36897608/6352712 please

Answer (score 0):

Scroll the recyclerview to last position

```
messagesView.scrollToPosition(messages.size()-1);
```

Where `messages` is your list of messages.

Comment: I don't want to manually scroll to position. Actually there is some provision setReverseLayout but even that is not working for me.

Comment: `layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);`? This is also not working?

Answer (score 0):

Use these line after you send/receive message event.

```
   mRecyclerView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mRecyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount());
                        }
                    }, 100);
```