# Black Screen Above Elements

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm having an awkward error, and do not have any clue about what's the cause.
I'm working on a maintenance of an android map application, it was using GoogleMap API, but now I've changed it to MapLink API. One of the view is this one:

```
<LinearLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Busca"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_weight="0.85" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/searchBtn"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/magnifier13"
        android:onClick="search" />

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/separator1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dip"
    android:background="@color/red" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" >


    <br.com.maplink.map.MapTemplate
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </br.com.maplink.map.MapTemplate>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/drag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/androidpin64"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/separator2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="@color/red" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtEtiqueta"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Etiqueta"
        android:maxLines="1" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:onClick="create"
        android:id="@+id/btnCadastrarPOI"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:text="Concluído" />
</LinearLayout>
```

When I click on the top textbox the keyboard just appear and when it's dismissed everything is normal, but when I click on the bottom textbox, the keyboard scroll the content page up and the content above the map goes off the view, when the keyboard is dismissed the content page scrolls back to it's original, but the content above the map is covered by a black frame, if I rotate the device or try to click on the top text box the black frame disappear.
I've already tried to recreate the view on other file but it keep this problem, I've tried the same thing on other project and everything is working fine.
Also, this problem only happen on landscape orientation;

Thanks.

Comment: The problem might be the keyboard is resizing the map. Here you can get some help and can give it a try.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21201569/android-resize-only-parts-of-view-with-soft-keyboard-on-screen

Comment: Thanks, this link give me the hint that I was needing