# Image resizing issue when keyboard open in android mobile

Tags: android, css, cordova, html5-appcache, html-framework-7

Thanks for reading, i am new in cordova developing, i am use framework7 to develop hybrid app using cordova.
I am putting background on login form, but in mobile when open keyboard for writing then background image is resized. 
I want fix position of image which is not resized when open android keyboard.
Please see image below

[image]

thanks

Comment: have you managed to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try these configuration

1. **Index.html**

`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width, height=device-height">`

2. **config.xml**

`<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustPan" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />`