# when Softkeyboard is visible toolbar push up

Tags: android, android-edittext

I get into trouble with an error. I searched a lot and found some solutions then applied but couldn't solve my problem. when i click `edittext` my `toolbar` push up and is not seen. I try to [Android: Resize only parts of view with soft keyboard on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21201569/android-resize-only-parts-of-view-with-soft-keyboard-on-screen) this soluction but can 't get result.How can i solve this problem?
`

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scroll_comment"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footerrr">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="Android charting application xml ui design tutorial with example. Android charting application xml ui design tutorial with example. Android charting application xml ui design tutorial with example. Android charting application xml ui design tutorial with example."
                android:textColor="#000" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layout1"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="Android charting application xml ui design. Android charting application xml ui design tutorial with example. Android charting application xml ui design. Android charting application xml ui design. "
                android:textColor="#000" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layout2"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="Android charting application xml ui design tutorial with example. Android charting application xml ui design tutorial with example. Android charting application xml ui design tutorial with example. Android charting application xml ui design tutorial with example."
                android:textColor="#000" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layout3"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="Android charting application xml ui design. Android charting application xml ui design tutorial with example. Android charting application xml ui design. Android charting application xml ui design. "
                android:textColor="#000" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/footerrr">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColorHint="#CFD8DC"
        android:textColor="#CFD8DC"
        android:hint="Write a message"
        android:id="@+id/edittt"
        android:focusable="true"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`[image]

[image]

Comment: post your xml full code ??

Comment: Why do you need to see the toolbar while you type?

Answer (score 0):

As you are not posting the `Xml` code I write the direct solution is to you have to add `android:isScrollContainer="false"` property to your `ScrollView` it will solve the problem.

Code this way

```
<ScrollView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:isScrollContainer="false" >
</ScrollView>
```