# How to disable Scrollview

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I have `ScrollView` and inside that a `TabLayout`. How can I disable the `ScrollView` from scrolling without effecting on `TabLayout` scroll?

**EDIT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/scrollview"
android:background="@color/backgroundView"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:scrollbars="none"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/slider_height"
            android:background="@drawable/border_light"
            >
                      app:pv_progressStyle="@style/LightInColorCircularProgressView"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
            <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_slider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/slider_height"

                />

            <com.daimajia.slider.library.Indicators.PagerIndicator
                android:id="@+id/custom_indicator"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/AndroidImageSlider_Corner_Oval"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>




                .... other stuff


        <com.rey.material.widget.TabPageIndicator
            style="@style/TabPageIndicator"
            android:id="@+id/main_tpi"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:clipToPadding="true"
            app:tpi_mode="scroll"
            app:tpi_indicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:background="@color/overlayView"/>

        <adapters.CustomViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/main_vp"

            />

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763304/disable-scrollview-programmatically

Comment: @madlymad check the edit please

Comment: Why do you use ScrollView if you want to disable it?

Comment: @IlyaBlokh I want to pin the tablayout to top , as you see it is in bottom but when scroll goes to top I want to disable it so the tab's viewPager only can scroll

Comment: Although I don't get the hole functionality of the app, I believe that we ought to use the expected functionally of the controllers and not trick our users. So use simple controllers without complicated scrolls or complicated enable, disable algorithms. ;-)

Comment: @madlymad what is your suggestion ?!

Comment: I haven't tried something similar so I am not sure how you could achieve this. There are some libraries that pin tabs or actionbar on top. Also, some of the Android compatibility packages contains such an example... Have you checked out how they do it? IMO. When you scroll up it pins when down unpin. So no need to disable something. Depending on the number and context of the tabs you may use the fillviewport so as to avoid the horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

I used this and it  worked for me :

```
// Get the ScrollView
final ScrollView myScroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.display_scrollview);


// Disable Scrolling by setting up an OnTouchListener to do nothing
myScroll.setOnTouchListener( new OnTouchListener(){ 
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true; 
    }
});


// Enable Scrolling by removing the OnTouchListner
tvDisplayScroll.setOnTouchListener(null);
```

happy programming......!!!

Comment: it's disable the scrollview but the tablayout scroll disabled also