# Android ScrollView inside Scrollview, How to Disable the parent?

Tags: android, scrollview

I have layout with a ScrollView and another one inside it , is there any way to disable the parent without effecting on the child's scrolling?

Comment: Try this `scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return isBlockedScrollView;
        }
    });`

Comment: @BNK the paret disabled but the child disabled also

Comment: Read this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763304/disable-scrollview-programmatically