# How to disable horizontal scroll when user drags on the screen in recycler view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have developed an app which contains a horizontal `RecyclerView` with two `Buttons` (back/forward) when clicked on the button the `child view` `scroll` to the respective position ( for forward it scrolls to position+1 and back is scrolled to position-1).

But the user can also `drag` the screen to left or right the view the next or previous view. I just want to disable that the user can't drag the screen left or right to view the next or previous child views.

But when clicked on the button it will `scroll` forward or backwards according to the selection.

Comment: I have tried 
linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context) {
 @Override
 public boolean canScrollVertically() {
  return false;
 }
};
but it completely disables the horizontal scroll and even it does not scolls to the posiiton when clicked on the button

Comment: disable touch of recyclerview

Comment: If you want to disable scroll by user then check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763304/disable-scrollview-programmatically

Comment: Maybe `ViewPager` suits your needs better.