# How can I disable ScrollView scrolling if it's not needed?

Tags: android

My UI consists of a ScrollView that takes the top 50% of the screen and under that two buttons that are attached to the bottom of the screen; YES and NO.  The content of Scrollview is text that for most phones does not fill up the visual area of the ScrollView. However sometimes the text can be longer, such that it fills beyond the visual area of the ScrollView, hence the reason I added the ScrollView.

My problem is this; even when the ScrollView has very little text and does not need to scroll to show all of its content it still scrolls. The user can scroll the content up a slight amount. I'd like the View to instead not allow any scrolling if all the content is visible.

Is there an easy way to achieve this? Or do I have to implement that myself?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable the scrolling of a ScrollView. You would need to extend to ScrollView and override the onTouchEvent method to return false when some condition is matched. To get help with extending, please read the answers to [Disable ScrollView Programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763304/disable-scrollview-programmatically)